# Can objects created by Performance of Creation be used as expensive material components?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, spell-components

*Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* introduces the College of Creation which gets the class feature Performance of Creation:

> As an action, you can channel the magic of the Song of Creation to create one nonmagical item of your choice in an unoccupied space within 10 feet of you. The item must appear on a surface or in a liquid that can support it. The gp value of the item can’t be more than 20 times your bard level, and the item must be Medium or smaller.

...this isn't a huge deal since there is a gold limit, so the cost of what you could reach is fairly small, but later on the College grants:

> **Creative Crescendo**
>
> [...]
>
> You are no longer limited by gp value when creating items with Performance of Creation.

Could you create expensive nonmagical objects such as a diamond for resurrection magic, or the 500 gp statue for *imprisonment*? Would it work when casting these spells?

Comment: Now we know where all of those expensive diamonds and rubies come from: DeBard's Gems, Ltd.  

Comment: *Item must be medium or smaller* and *you are no longer limited by GP value* is a dangerous combo. Does a 5' cube of sulfuric acid count as a single item?

Comment: @RevenantBacon is it frozen? If  not, it won't remain a 'cube' for much longer.

Comment: @RevenantBacon I'd apply general English here. If you go to the store, do you buy "a water", or do you buy "a bottle of water"? Similarly, I'd say "a 5' glass container with sulfuric acid" is one item, whereas 125 cubic feet of acid is not. Otherwise, the ocean might as well also be an item.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast That's the idea :p

Comment: Related: [Can the School of Conjuration wizard's Minor Conjuration feature be used to summon rare, expensive, and/or consumable spell components?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/62704/63795)

Comment: @RevenantBacon Actually, the size limit of the item increases to Large at 6th level and Huge at 14th level. So it would actually be _item must be huge or smaller_ and _you are no longer limited by gp value_.

Comment: Related: [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/202939/23547) to [What's the RAW most efficient way to mine for diamonds?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/202823/23547)

Answer (score 13):

I would assume that was the intention of the feature, as the similar spell [Creation](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Creation#content) includes this line:

> Using any material created by this spell as another spell’s material component causes that spell to fail.

Barring any sort of errata or correction, there doesn't seem to be any RAW reason why a 14th level creation bard can't just magic up the diamond worth 25000gp required for True Resurrection

Update: Crawford has clarified:
*The Performance of Creation feature in Tasha's Cauldron of Everything can create objects that are usable as the material components of D&D spells, as long as you abide by the limitations in the feature. [#DnD](https://twitter.com/hashtag/DnD?src=hash&ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw) https://t.co/iTLTJ2ph3E*

— Jeremy Crawford (@JeremyECrawford) [December 5, 2020](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1335026971940585472?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw)

Comment: Late to this, but surely part of value is the ability to last a while. Can something be worth 25k if it only lasts a short time? I don't think it can.

Comment: @SeriousBri sure it can be worth it, if that means your friend lives. Amount of time it would exist if you wouldn't use it seems irrelevant in this case, doesn't it?

Comment: @Mołot worth is usually defined by more than one person, a speck of diamond dust might be 'worth it' to the person scrambling to save a friend, but it's not worth it in the grand scheme of things, and I would expect the gods who set the spell rules to care about that more than the moment, otherwise they wouldn't have bothered with needing it at all

Comment: @SeriousBri what you write has no reflection in the rules. You assume D&D economy makes sense when it quite obviously doesn't, rules-wise.

Comment: @Mołot can you find any examples of short lived items having a proper value? You probably can't, because they don't. When a term (like value) isn't specifically defined then the real language version takes over. Game value is like real value, there are costs set, but there is never a cost set for "diamond that will only last 6 hours" because it isn't worth anything

Comment: @SeriousBri In the real world, lots of things that are short lived have a proper value. Experiences come to mind, including things like a play. It is a very short lived, but people pay to be able to have the experience all the time. Lots of other things have a short shelf life before they expire and become worthless including certain types of fruits and vegetables and some medications. But they still find a market and have prices. And those are in the real world where values kind-of-sort-of make sense. The D&D economy has never tried to make a lot of sense...

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman that's very tangential to a temporary 25k diamond.

Comment: @SeriousBri I respect your opinion and this is an area where reasonable people can disagree. But I do disagree. Its not a tangent. Temporary things have value in the real world. This would even be true of a temporary diamond. People rent high-end clothing and jewelry. Obviously at a fraction of the value of owning it, which is the point, but they do still have value.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman that's kinda proving my point, temporary existing or ownership isn't 'worth' full value. Your other point about fruit was a tangent because the value of the fruit isn't in the ownership, it's in the consumption. Diamonds aren't really a consumable, their value is in ownership, and if you can't own one it isn't going to be worth the same as one you could own

Comment: If you walked into a store and saw 2 diamonds for sale, both 25k but one with a sign saying "only last 6 hours" nobody in the right mind would pick the temporary one and still pay full price. If I saw 2 cartons of juice I wouldn't care if one lasted a day or so longer, because I intend to get my value out of that juice much quicker.

Comment: That doesn't really apply. First, the statement I've been arguing against is your claim that a short lived items have no proper value. They very much do. Second, even your new statement implicit assumes that the diamonds are of roughly equal quality. If I need formal attire for a very important event, renting a high end tux for 6 hours might be worth more to me than buying a suit from Sears.

Comment: @TimothyAWiseman value to you at an exact moment in time isn't value in the true sense, that is the point. A diamond that might save your wifes life may well in that moment be worth everything you own and eternal servitude in the afterlife but the diamond still needs 25k of normal value to a normal person at a normal time.

Comment: @SeriousBri I think perhaps we are using different versions of value. But people in the real world seek for, desire for, and are willing to work and pay for transient things all the time. How long something will last might certainly affect the value of something, but as the term is normally used transient things certainly can have value, and sometimes a very substantial value at that.

Answer (score 0):

### Nothing indicates the item cannot be used as a component

There is no Sage Advice on this feature, so we are looking at official rules content from pulished books.

Creative Crescendo is a modification of the 3rd level Performance of Creation feature (partially quoted in the question), which also says this

> The item glimmers softly, and a creature can faintly hear music when
> touching it. The created item disappears after a number of hours equal to your proficiency bonus. For examples of items you can create, see the equipment chapter of the *Player's Handbook*. (...) The size of the item you can create with this feature increases by one size category when you reach
> 6th level (Large) and 14th level (Huge).

Creative Crescendo's full text says:

> When you use your Performance of Creation feature, you can create more than one item at once. The number of items equals your Charisma modifier (minimum of two items). If you create an item that would exceed that number, you choose which of the previously created items disappears. Only one of these items can be of the maximum size you can create; the rest must be Small or Tiny. **You are no longer limited by gp value when creating items with Performance of Creation.**

This means that the item

- must be nonmagical
- glimmers softly, and a creature can faintly hear music when
  touching it
- disappears after a number of hours equal to your proficiency bonus
- can at most be Huge (or Tiny or Small for subsequent items)
- has no limite to its gp value

So, at first look, there is no reason you would not be able to create a non-magical diamond worth 25,000 gp that glimmers softly.

The game rules simplify the value of objects, by assinging a fixed gp value to things such as jewels, clothing or silver ingots. In reality, the value of an item is always dependent on if there is someone willing to pay the price, but that is not how value of items is measured in game, even though it may influence what the PCs can sell an item for, independent of its inherent value. In-game, NPCs might be very well unwilling to pay much of anything for a suspiciously glimmering diamond that lets you hear faint music when you touch it, if they suspect that the object may be a transient magical fakery. Technically though, it still is a 25,000 gp diamond, even if nobody is willing to give even 100 gp to the characters to purchase it from them.

#### Comparisons

**Creation**. The first comparator is the [creation](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/creation) spell. This spell cannot create usable material components, as it includes a statement that

> Using any material created by this spell as another spell's material component causes that spell to fail.

This is a 5th level spell, while the feature, as a level 14 feature, would only be available to bards with access to 7th level spells. The feature lacks any such language that would block use as a spell component.

**Minor Conjuration**. The second comparator is the minor conjuration feature of the Conjuration wizard. This becomes available much earlier, and it is less clear if it could create components of value, as it makes no statement about the value of the created objects. The [current consensus](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/62704/can-the-school-of-conjuration-wizards-minor-conjuration-feature-be-used-to-summ) answer is that it seems to be allowed by the rules text, but should be expected to be ruled out by the DM, as it invalidates the cost of such components nearly entirely. The same reasoning could apply to Crescendo too, but Crescendo has explicit language about the unlimited gp value of the created components that this is lacking.

**Wish**. The *[wish](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish)* spell, for a 9th level spell, allows this: "*You create one object of up to 25,000 gp in value that isn't a magic item.*". This is two spell levels higher, but in exchange the item has no suspicious glimmer or faint music, and it is permanent. The diamond here certainly could be used as a spell component, as this is again not excluded, and seems legitimate from a balance perspecive, considering that you can cast any non-9th level spell without need for its components, anyways.

#### Balance and playabiltiy

Few campaigns get far beyond to level 14. If you follow the rules, allowing this might allow the characters in a typcial campaign to get maybe a handful of uses out of it during the last level or two. It still is value, a typical PC would have about 57,000 gp in wealth by level 14, but since there are normally no magic items to buy, buying expensive components would seem like a natural use, meaning that getting them for free with this may affect balance less than if the PCs did not have access to such gems.

In the end, I think a DM should decide if they are comfortable with this, but there is noting in the rules that contradicts this being possible.

Comment: Did you just compare it to wish as a reason for it being valid? Also I can't get behind that technicality on cost, things have a value because the writers needed to put a value on things so they could give treasure, given the state of the economy there was no further thought put into it.

Comment: What I mean is wish can create components too, so why would this not? Wish us better as you'll find someone to pay for them, and you can use them long term, which makes sense as it is also higher level access gated. I fully agree that the economy rules in the game are a mess if you think deeper about it, because for playability the writers needed to put fixed values on things.

Comment: I would probably allow it in all honesty, but the fact that wish is the only thing that can specifically do it tells me that lesser features probably shouldn't be able to more than anything. If the bard was making these and selling them and playing the charlatan then bad things would end up happening, this is the equivelent of doing that with a god