# Can I use Performance of Creation to provide the 100gp gem for a homunculus servant?

Tags: dnd-5e, bard, artificer, artificer-infusions

The College of Creation Bard has the class feature Performance of Creation, which states:

> As an action, you can channel the magic of the Song of Creation to create one nonmagical item of your choice in an unoccupied space within 10 feet of you. […] The gp value of the item can't be more than 20 times your bard level, and the item must be Medium or smaller.

Homunculus Servant is an Artificer infusion which requires "A gem or crystal worth at least 100gp" to serve as its heart.

Assuming that I'm a 5 Bard/2 Artificer build who took Homunculus Servant as one of my infusions, would I be able to make a 100 gp gem, then infuse it to be the heart of my Homunculus Servant, which would then die after an hour?

*As I'm writing this, I'm beginning to think this is another situation where you think so long about if you could, and forget to think if you should.*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Yes. The gem would vanish after 3 hours

The item created with college of creation fulfills all the requirements for the infusion: it is a gem, it is stated to be nonmagical (in spite of some unusual properties like light and faint music), and it is worth 100 gp. You even can use these items [as spell components](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177552/75095).

The College of Creation feature also states that:

> The created item disappears after a number of hours equal to your proficiency bonus.

As a level 7 character, your proficiency bonus is 3, so the item would vanish after 3 hours.

The Homunculus Servant feature says:

> The item you infuse serves as the creature's heart, around which the creature's body instantly forms.

Without the item existing any more, you have no infused item, and no heart for the servant. So the effect would end.

#### Why do this?

It is not clear to me what the benefit of this would be for you, unless you somehow had difficulty to afford or obtain a 100 gp gem (which you normally should not on level 7, and the gem is also not consumed, so the value is conserved). Normally infusions have no time limit. The infusion feature also says:

> **Whenever you finish a long rest**, you can touch a nonmagical object and imbue it with one of your artificer infusions

So you could not immediately reuse your infusion, either.

Possible uses could be for example

- if you wanted to avoid redoing all your infusions to get rid of this one, in case it was the last one you made,
- or you can have the servant deliver a message and then vanish
  without leaving a trace,
- or you are in a prison cell without
  equipment and want to create a servant to fetch the key.

So there are some edge cases, where this could be of help, but they seem rather fringe.

Comment: The advantage is clearly not paying for/obtaining the 100gp gem. Though I agree that in the scheme of things 100gp isn't a big cost.

Comment: @linksassin Good point, will add that

Comment: The last one (prison escape) seems like a very useful use case

Answer (score 3):

### This works for a number of hours equal to your proficiency

A gem or crystal is "one nonmagical item" and therefore can be created by the the Performance of Creation feature. It will "[disappear] after a number of hours equal to your proficiency bonus", so at level 7 that is 3 hours.

The question is if you are able to use this as your target object for an artificer infusion. I don't believe any rules exist which explicitly say you can't do this. [An answer to related question on using it as a spell component](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177552/48759) rules that you can as it is missing the relevant restriction from the [Creation](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Creation#content) spell:

> Using any material created by this spell as another spell’s material component causes that spell to fail.

Which is [unofficially confirmed by Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/1335026971940585472?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw). Therefore yes this should work, and will last a number of hours equal to your proficiency modifier.